# Find the values of variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $2^a+4^b+8^c=328$
Then how do I find the value of $\frac{a+2b+3c}{abc}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you forgot to write something (?). What are your attempts?

Comment: 2a+2.2b+2.3c=328

Comment: Now I cant find the way how to do it

Comment: Click on the "edit" button below your question and make the relevant changes to your question in order for me and others to understand. Take a quick look to MathJax to better write your questions http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Can you please solve the question

Comment: Right now I can't understand your question. Anyway, an answer was added, but remember we want to see your effort when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question means $$2^a+4^b+8^c=328$$ We proceed by dividing both sides by $8$. $$2^{a-3} + 2^{2b-3}+2^{3c-3} = 41$$ $$\Rightarrow 2^{a-3}+2^{2b-3}+8^{c-1} = 41$$ $c-1$ should be $1$. So, $c=2$. This gives, $$2^{a-3}+2^{2b-3} = 33$$ It can be easily checked that $a-3 = 0, 2b-3 = 5$. This gives $a=3, b=4$. The answer can now be easily obtained.

---

**EDIT**: Also possible that $a-3 = 5, 2b-3=0$.

Comment: How you assumed that 8^c-1 =1

Comment: Think what are the powers of $8$. It can be $0,8,64\cdots$. A simple analysis for $8^0=1$ gives us no answers. The next case can be used. But, $64$ can't be possible as the sum of the other two quantities cannot be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $328$ in base two, we get
$$
328=2^3+2^6+2^8
$$
Even if $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$, we have three solutions:
$$
2^3+4^4+8^2=328\implies\frac{a+2b+3c}{abc}=\frac{17}{24}
$$
$$
2^6+4^4+8^1=328\implies\frac{a+2b+3c}{abc}=\frac{17}{24}
$$
$$
2^8+4^3+8^1=328\implies\frac{a+2b+3c}{abc}=\frac{17}{24}
$$
Luckily, all three give the same value.